# Node process won't start with bot

Tags: node.js, heroku, bots

I am trying to deploy a bot to run on Heroku servers. It fails to compile the app when I try to commit. Here is my `package.json`

```
{
"name": "Bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bot.js"
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

`bot.js` is the correct name for the bot configuration file. It works fine when I take out `start: node bot.js` but the bot doesn't come online of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Changing `main` to `bot.js`.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs